# Different range price data on one chart

Tags: normalization

I'd like to evaluate 3-4 instruments on one price chart.
For example:

- Stock A: 90,05 90,15 90,25 90,09
- Stock B: 0,0045 0,0049 0,0039 0,0040
- Stock C: 1998,1 1998,7 1998,8 1997

I try to use:

- Ln(close) - too different values, to put them on one chart, same results with Close(0)-Average(10)
- returns Close(0)-Close(-1), (Close(0)-Close(-1))*100/Close(-1) - deviations are too small for evaluating
  [image: returns charts]
  Is there any way to normalize different price data on one Y axis to get look like this
  [image: 3 stocks on one chart]

Answer (score 2):

have you tried to rebase the timeseries? if the start and end dates are same, you could basically have 100*(1+returns). easy to then plot either directly or log of the new time series.